# ¿Cómo realizar left trim, right trim y global en Android?

Tags: java, android

Cómo se podría realizar las siguientes modificaciones
`leftTrim, rightTrim y allTrim`

**Dummy text**, el carácter  `.` resaltado visual.

```
...Lorem...ipsum...
```

**Salida**

lefTrim() `Lorem...ipsum...`

rightTrim() `...Lorem...ipsum`

trim() `Lorem...ipsum` Este ya lo soporta nativamente el objeto String

allTrim() `Loremipsum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SO he recopilado las siguientes soluciones, usando expresiones regulares

Para realizar un **left Trim**

```
public static String leftTrim(String str) {
   return str.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
}
```

Para realizar un **right Trim**

```
public static String rightTrim(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s+$","");
}
```

Y para realizar un **trim global** Izquierda, derecha y los espacios del medio

```
public static String allTrim(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
}
```

**Update**
He modificado después del apunte de @LuiggiMendoza, para que tenga en cuenta caracteres diferentes a un `espacio en blanco/tabulador` y también se le puede indicar el total de caracteres a eliminar, independientemente si se están repitiendo o no.

```
public static String leftTrim(String s) {
   return s.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
}

public static String leftTrim(String s, String c) {
   return s.replaceAll("^" + c + "+","");
}

public static String leftTrim(String s, int n) {
    int l =s.length();
    if (n<0) n= 0;
    if (n > l) n = l;
    return s.substring(n);
}

public static String rightTrim(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\s+$","");
}

    public static String rightTrim(String s, String c) {
    return s.replaceAll(c +"+$","");
}

public static String rightTrim(String s, int n) {
    int l =s.length();
    if (n<0) n= 0;
    if (n > l) n = l;
    return s.substring(0, s.length() - n);
}


public static String trim(String s) {
    s = leftTrim(s);
    s = rightTrim(s);
    return s;
}

public static String trim(String s, String c) {
    s = leftTrim(s,c);
    s = rightTrim(s,c);
    return s;
}

public static String trim(String s, int n) {
    s = leftTrim(s,n);
    s = rightTrim(s,n);
    return s;
}


public static String allTrim(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\s+","");
}

public static String allTrim(String s, String c) {
    return s.replaceAll(c + "+","");
}
```

Comment: Para el trim global puedes utilizar `String#trim` que ya viene implementado en el JDK. Ojo que tu pregunta es hacer trim de un caracter en particular, no de espacios en blanco solamente. Tu respuesta solo cubre espacios en blanco.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte, intentaré de modificar esas funciones para que se puede indicar el carácter repetitivo